# conversion of text area to file with save draft feature in cloud

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, cloud

Is it possible to convert content in text area to a file of desired format and store it in the cloud? and every change made in the text area should be reflected in the file stored in the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you probably can. Read around about FileOutputStream.
And a cloud https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/java
Dropbox has a little API page to read up on. Slam those togeather and you'll have what you need